# Get location in android (problems with callback)

Tags: android, kotlin, location

I'm trying to get the user's new location.
This is the code I have so far:

```
 private fun getNewLocation() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getNewLocation: started")
    locationRequest = LocationRequest()
    locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    locationRequest.interval = 0
    locationRequest.fastestInterval = 0
    locationRequest.numUpdates = 1
    fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
        locationRequest,
        locationCallback,
        Looper.myLooper()
    )
    Log.d(TAG, "getNewLocation: finished")
}

private val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
    override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "locationCallback: onLocationResult started")
        val newLocation = locationResult.lastLocation
        Log.d(TAG, "locationCallback: before setting new data latitude = $latitude, longitude = $longitude")
        // set new location
        latitude = newLocation.latitude.toString()
        longitude = newLocation.longitude.toString()
        locationName = getLocationName(newLocation.latitude, newLocation.longitude)
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastLocation: new location were set latitude = $latitude, longitude = $longitude")
        requestAPI()
    }
}
```

For some reason, when I test it on a physical device `getNewLocation()` doesn't call `onLocationResult`
so my Logs look like this:

```
D/MainActivity: getNewLocation: started
D/MainActivity: getNewLocation: finished
```

Instead of:

```
D/MainActivity: getNewLocation: started
D/MainActivity: getNewLocation: finished
D/MainActivity: locationCallback: onLocationResult started
D/MainActivity: locationCallback: latitude = 64.49273, longitude = 40.596625
```

I've also tried to set `newLocation` in `locationCallback` like this:

```
val newLocation = locationResult.locations[0]
```

But I have the same result since the problem is in fact that `getNewLocation()` doesn't call `onLocationResult`

Can anyone please help me to understand the reason why is it happening this way and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should check location settings before request a new location

```
private suspend fun checkSettings(locationRequest: LocationRequest) {
    val settingsRequest = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
        .addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
        .build()
    try {
        LocationServices
            .getSettingsClient(this)
            .checkLocationSettings(settingsRequest)
            .await()
        // location is turned on
    } catch (e: ResolvableApiException) {
        // location is turned off. Prompt the user to enable it
        e.startResolutionForResult(this, CODE)
    }
}
```

Also if you are using the latest version of play-services-location, there is a easy way to get a new location

```
LocationServices
    .getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    .getCurrentLocation(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, null)
```